# Stopwatch stop/start button and reset

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, timers

i am trying to make a stop watch with a stop/start button and a reset button

i have made this

```
#include "RTClib.h"
//Setup the Real Time Clock, DS3231
RTC_DS3231 rtc;

const byte SQWinput = 2;  // Must be External Interrupt

volatile uint32_t  MillisecondsAtStartOfSecond = 0;
 
 unsigned long secondss=0 ;
 unsigned long minutess=0 ;
 
 unsigned long  hourss =0;
 unsigned long ms;

boolean passed_second=true;
boolean start=true;


const byte ledPin = 13;

const byte startButton = 7;


const byte resetButton = 3;
// Instantiate another Bounce object


const char daysOfTheWeek[7][12] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

// The SQW pin, when set to 1 Hz mode, has a falling edge at the beginning of every second.
void SQWFallingISR()
{
  MillisecondsAtStartOfSecond = millis();
}

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); // Set Serial Monitor to 115200
  delay(200);

  pinMode(7, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
  pinMode(3, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
 


  
  if (! rtc.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    Serial.flush();
    abort();
  }

  if (rtc.lostPower())
  {
    Serial.println("RTC lost power, let's set the time!");
    // When time needs to be set on a new device, or after a power loss, the
    // following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
    rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
    // This line sets the RTC with an explicit date & time, for example to set
    // January 21, 2014 at 3am you would call:
    // rtc.adjust(DateTime(2022, 4, 03, 21, 14, 0));
  }

  // Configure SQW pin on the DS3231 to output a 1Hz squarewave 
  rtc.writeSqwPinMode(DS3231_SquareWave1Hz);

  // Get MillisecondsAtStartOfSecond on the falling edge of SQW.
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(SQWinput), SQWFallingISR, FALLING);
}



void loop ()
{
  DateTime now = rtc.now();


    ms = millis();
 
  noInterrupts();
  // How long since the second started?
  
 
  ms -= MillisecondsAtStartOfSecond;
  interrupts();

  if(digitalRead(7) != HIGH)   //START BUTTON
{    displayTime (now, ms);
     Serial.println("stopwatch  ");
  
  Serial.print(hourss);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(minutess);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(secondss);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.println(ms);
}

 if(digitalRead(3) != HIGH)   //RESET BUTTON
{
     Serial.println("stopwatch  ");
  
  Serial.print(0);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(0);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(0);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.println(0);
  ms=0;
}
 // displayTime (now, ms);
  /*Serial.println("stopwatch  ");
  
  Serial.print(hourss);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(minutess);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(secondss);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.println(ms);
  Serial.println("*********************************");
  Serial.println("Clock & Date  ");*/
   

  }

void displayTime(DateTime &now, unsigned long ms)
{
  ms = ms % 1000;  // Ignore full seconds
  
  Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
  Serial.print(" (");
  Serial.print(daysOfTheWeek[now.dayOfTheWeek()]);
  Serial.print(") ");
  Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
  Serial.print(':');
  if (now.minute() < 10)
    Serial.print('0');
  Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
  Serial.print(':');
  if (now.second() < 10)
    Serial.print('0');
  Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
 // Serial.println();
  Serial.print(':');
  if (ms < 100)
    Serial.print('0');
  if (ms < 10)
    Serial.print('0');
  Serial.print(ms, DEC);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("*********************************");

  if(ms>998) {
      secondss++;
     
  }
    if(secondss>59) {
     secondss=0;
      minutess++;
 
    }
    if(minutess>59) {
     minutess=0;
      hourss++;}

    }
```

but it is not working properly

the time is not incrementing after ms reaches 999

what is causing this?

Comment: What do you mean by “_it is not working properly_”? What behavior do you see? How is it different from the behavior you expect?

Comment: the time is not incrementing after ms reaches 999

Comment: declare `now` in `setup()` ... `DateTime now;` .... then use `now = rtc.now();` in `loop()`

Answer (score 4):

This code is quite confusing, as you are using both `millis()` and an
RTC as time sources.

Your problem may come from here:

```cpp
ms -= MillisecondsAtStartOfSecond;
```

If the internal clock of your Arduino is a bit off, it may happen that
an RTC second is only 999 milliseconds from `millis()`. If that happens,
then `ms` will never hit 999, and will instead go straight from 998
to 0.

Or maybe it's here:

```cpp
ms = ms % 1000;  // Ignore full seconds
// ...
if (ms > 998) {
    secondss++;
}
```

If you sketch is busy (maybe it is communicating with the RTC), it may
not run this code precisely at millisecond 999. And 999 is the only
value of `ms` that can possibly increment `secondss`.

For a stopwatch, you don't really need the RTC data. You can implement
it entirely on the basis of `millis()`, and that would simplify things:

```cpp
bool stop_watch_running;
uint32_t stop_watch_last_update;
uint16_t stop_watch_ms;
uint8_t stop_watch_s;
uint8_t stop_watch_min;
uint8_t stop_watch_h;

void stop_watch_reset() {
    stop_watch_running = false;
    stop_watch_ms = 0;
    stop_watch_s = 0;
    stop_watch_min = 0;
    stop_watch_h = 0;
}

void stop_watch_start() {
    stop_watch_last_update = millis();
    stop_watch_running = true;
}

// Call this periodically.
void stop_watch_update() {
    if (!stop_watch_running)
        return;
    uint32_t now = millis();
    stop_watch_ms += now - stop_watch_last_update;
    stop_watch_last_update = now;
    while (stop_watch_ms >= 1000) {
        stop_watch_ms -= 1000;
        stop_watch_s++;
        if (stop_watch_s >= 60) {
            stop_watch_s = 0;
            stop_watch_min++;
            if (stop_watch_min >= 60) {
                stop_watch_min = 0;
                stop_watch_h++;
            }
        }
    }
}

void stop_watch_stop() {
    stop_watch_update();
    stop_watch_running = false;
}
```

If you know a bit about C++ classes, you may want to turn this into a
class, and replace the `stop_watch_` prefix with `StopWatch::`.

Comment: Hello Edgar 
Thank u v much for your code
RTC is used to get sq wave output